# how to get the JSON data from http request in swift2.0, xcode7.3

Tags: json, swift, http, get

I am trying to write a method that scan the barcode then using http rest call to get some JSON data from a server. Alamofire doesn't work now and I tried many different ways.

Here is what I got now:

```
let getEndpoint: String = "45.55.63.218:8080/food?foodidentifier=\(code)"
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: getEndpoint)!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
            do{
                //let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }
task.resume()
```

I get an error message:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) on line: `let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse`

Comment: By the way, in addition to needing to add the scheme (e.g. `http://` or `https://`), assuming it's only `http://`, then you might also need to add your domain to the `NSAppTransportSecurity` as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/31254874#31254874.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the forced cast to `NSHTTPURLResponse` will fail if `response` was `nil` (for example, if there was some error that prevented the request from being issued successfully, as in this case where the URL string was missing the `http://` scheme prefix; but this could happen for any of a variety of issues, so one must anticipate and handle network errors gracefully). When processing responses from network requests, one should studiously avoid forced unwrapping/casting unless you have first confirmed that the value is valid and non-`nil`.

I would suggest:

- using `guard` statements to safely check for `nil` values;
- check that `data` was not `nil` and that `error` was `nil` before bothering to check status codes;

So, that might yield:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { data, response, error in
    guard data != nil && error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        print("status code not 200; \(response)")
        return
    }

    print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
        print(json)
    } catch let parseError {
        print("Error with Json: \(parseError)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```